# How sending parameter in the controller method of Silex - PHP

Tags: php, routes, silex

I'm using silex and I'm trying to pass a parameter controllers , but do not work.

My code below:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class TestController
{
    public function testAction(Request $request, Application $app, $value)
    {
        var_dump($value);
        return 'test';
    }
}

$app = new Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

$app->get('/{value}', 'TestController::testAction');
$app->run();
```

Comment: What error or output are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct.

That's 404 error that you get is from apache. You need to call your page with `http://site/index.php/value`. If you want remove `index.php` from the url then [follow this page](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html).